# URL not found on this server?(Python)

Tags: python, php, sql, raspberry-pi3

I'm working on a project that sends delivered data from Raspberry to a SQL database and I am using "PHPMyAdmin". I managed to do a little experience to detect the source of error. And I've come to the conclusion that the problem remains in the URL of the "request.post()" method, that is meant to read my php file (the server code). When I run the program, I get a message saying "The requested URL was not found on this server".  So my question is: What am I suppose to provide in the URL address? Am I suppose to put my IP address? or just 127.0.0.1 ?

**Server code:**

```
<?php

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "test";



// this is just to test whether the connection is established and the data was inserted into my table successfully. Indeed, when I pass these as values for my new inserted data. Everything works fine.
$var1=12; 
$var2=133;

//But when I use these, my program doesn't work. Which means that the data wasn't sent by my python code
//$var1 = $_POST["var1"];
//$var2 = $_POST["var2"];

echo $var1;
echo $var2;

    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

    if ($conn->connect_error) 
    {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }
  
    $sql = "INSERT INTO test (var1, var2) VALUES ($var1, $var2)";

    if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) 
    {
        echo "New record created successfully!";
    }
    else 
    {
        echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
    }

    $conn->close();
?>
```

**Python code:**

```
import requests


var1=12
var2=13

datavars = {'var1': var1, 'var2': var2}

r = requests.post('http://localhost/Test/test.php, data=datavars') #PROBLEM HEEERE!!!Localhost??
print(r.text)
```

Comment: open `http://localhost` with your browser, if it works then should works. also you may try `http://127.0.0.1` instead, both are same

Answer (score 0):

After trying out your Python code example and a part of your PHP code as a test, I think the problem might relate to the use of quotes in your Python code.

In particular, the main problem seems to have to do with this line (as you discovered):

```
r = requests.post('http://localhost/Test/test.php, data=datavars')
```

This line should probably be written like this, instead:

```
r = requests.post('http://localhost/Test/test.php', data=datavars)
```

(See how the `''` marks go around the URL but how they now end before the `, data ...` part?)

[The related documentation for `requests`](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/quickstart/#make-a-request) also shows that the format for a POST should have a similar type of format:

```
r = requests.post('https://httpbin.org/post', data = {'key':'value'})
```

If you make that change to your Python code, it might help resolve the issue you are facing.

Here is the code I used (based on your code) to test this out:

**PHP Code:**

```
<?php
// ref: https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post
print_r($_POST);
?>
```

**Python Code:**

```
import requests

var1 = 12
var2 = 13

datavars = {'var1': var1, 'var2': var2}
# ref: https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/quickstart/#custom-headers
headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}

r = requests.post('http://localhost/Test/test.php', data=datavars, headers=headers)
print(r.text)
```

**Output from Python Code (with result from PHP Code):**

```
Array
(
    [var1] => 12
    [var2] => 13
)
```